# Removing Data with NAs for the whole quarter but not the whole dataset

Tags: r, filter, na

I have a dataset which contains data on companies over multiple quarters. Some companies have NA datapoints. In that case I need to remove the company data for the whole quarter but NOT for the whole dataset as data from other quarters might be complete.

```
Identifier     Quarter     Date          Value
a              2013.1      02-02-2013    1
a              2013.1      02-03-2013    2
a              2013.1      02-03-2013    NA
a              2014.1      02-02-2014    4
b              2014.1      02-03-2014    5
```

In the example above I would need to remove the data for company a for Q1 2013 but not for Q1 2014.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can group by 'Identifier', 'Quarter', if there is `any`, 'NA' elements in 'Value', `filter` out the rows for that 'Quarter'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(Identifier, Quarter) %>% 
     filter(!any(is.na(Value))
```

Comment: is this not a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293039/group-by-in-data-table-in-r-which-only-keep-non-na-values-from-columns

Comment: @NickDylla I'd say that one isn't a dupe because it's asking about data.table specifically and there's no indication the asker here is using that package.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan That's why I didn't dupe tag it. I left the link in the comments in case someone is using `data.table` and comes across this post before the other one.